# Finite groups which have elements $g$ of order $pq$ such that the sizes of the conjugacy classes of $g^p$, of $g^q$ and of $g^{q-p}$ coincide

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $g \in G$ be an element of order $pq$, where $p < q$ are 
prime numbers. Denote by $g^G$ the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$. Under which conditions
does the following hold?:
$$
 |(g^p)^G| = |(g^q)^G| = |(g^{q−p})^G|
$$
-- Is it possible that this happens?

Comment: I guess you could simplify $(g^{q-p})^G$ to $g^G$.

Comment: I cannot get your mean. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Why do you consider $G$ is of order $pq$?

Comment: Professor Robinson, you want to say that this equality does not happens, when $G\neq\langle g\rangle$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Is it possible that you misunderstood the question?

Comment: @milad: Don't you have $\langle g\rangle = \langle g^{q-p}\rangle$, so both have the same centralizer and therefore their conjugacy classes have the same size?

Comment: No. I know that $p\neq2$, so $\langle g\rangle\ne\langle g^{q-p}\rangle$

Comment: Even though I did misunderstand the question, j.p is correct: since $q-p$ is coprime to $p$ and $q$, it is coprime to $o(g)$, so that $g^{q-p}$ generates $\langle g \rangle$.

Comment: This was crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328886/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it trivially happens if $G = \langle g \rangle$ is the cyclic group
of order $pq$ -- then all $3$ conjugacy classes mentioned have precisely one element.
A smallest example of a nonabelian group $G$ having such an element is
$$
  G \ = \ \langle (1,3,2)(4,5)(6,7), (2,3)(5,7) \rangle, \ \ g \ = \ (1,2,3)(4,5)(6,7).
$$
Then $|G| = 24$, and we have $|(g^2)^G| = |(g^3)^G| = |(g^{3-2})^G| = 2$.

A nontrivial example where $p \neq 2$ is the following group of order $675$
and structure $(({\rm C}_5 \times {\rm C}_5) \rtimes {\rm C}_9) \rtimes {\rm C}_3$:

```
G = < (1,2,6,4,9,8,5,7,3)(10,15,23)(12,17,24)(13,18,22)(14,16,25)(19,29,28)
      (20,21,32)(26,27,33)(30,34,31)(35,40,48)(37,42,49)(38,43,47)(39,41,50)
      (44,54,53)(45,46,57)(51,52,58)(55,59,56)(60,65,73)(62,67,74)(63,68,72)
      (64,66,75)(69,79,78)(70,71,82)(76,77,83)(80,84,81), 
      (2,7,9)(3,6,8)(10,41,73,32,56,60,16,48,82,31,35,66,23,57,81)
      (11,45,79,33,59,61,20,54,83,34,36,70,29,58,84)   
      (12,46,80,24,43,62,21,55,74,18,37,71,30,49,68)
      (13,47,78,15,52,63,22,53,65,27,38,72,28,40,77) 
      (14,44,67,26,50,64,19,42,76,25,39,69,17,51,75) >
```

-- when choosing the element

```
g = (2,7,9)(3,6,8)(10,41,73,32,56,60,16,48,82,31,35,66,23,57,81)
    (11,45,79,33,59,61,20,54,83,34,36,70,29,58,84)
    (12,46,80,24,43,62,21,55,74,18,37,71,30,49,68)
    (13,47,78,15,52,63,22,53,65,27,38,72,28,40,77)
    (14,44,67,26,50,64,19,42,76,25,39,69,17,51,75),
```

we have $|(g^3)^G| = |(g^5)^G| = |(g^{5-3})^G| = 3$.

Comment: So it doesn't happen when $G$ is not cyclic?

Comment: @milad: It can happen ...

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it can happen in your example. But in your example $q-p=1$ so the size of conjugacy classes of $g^p$ and $g^q$ are equal with $|g^G|$. If $p\neq2$, then this equality happen?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen in a non-Abelian group for any choice of primes $p < q.$ Take a prime $r \equiv 1$ (mod $pq$), and let $G$ be a Frobenius group of order $pqr$ with kernel $K$ of order $r$ and cyclic complement $H$ of order $pq$ ( this can be done as as a cyclic group of order $r$ has a cyclic automorphism group of order $r-1$ and  each non-identity automorphism fixes 
no non-identity element). Let $g$ be a generator of $H$. Then $C_{G}(g^{i}) = H$ for $1 \leq i < pq$,so that the conjugacy classes of $g^{p},g^{q}$ and $g^{q-p}$ all have size $r$.